# live music visualisation

Tags: real-time

Does anyone out there know of any software for developing real time visualisations and analysis of real time sound, say using a mike? I've found a few but none allow the user to build up their own visualisations.

Thanks for any ideas, Jonathan

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe your problem or need and the steps, if any, you've taken to solve it. See also [What topics can I ask about here?](http://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One tool I've seen people use for this sort of thing is [Processing](https://processing.org/), a Java-based language for real-time artsy stuff that supports graphics and audio. I haven't ever worked with it myself, but apparently it's pretty easy to use it for programming visualizations. [Here's an example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a-Ht7d-tECY) of a simple visualization someone made; look in the video description for a link to their code—it's quite short. Their example loads an mp3 file, but Processing also supports real-time input from a mic.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Must try it, there are a good few demos on youtube, but I had never seen any mentioning live imput from mike.

Answer (score 1):

[Shadertoy](https://www.shadertoy.com/) is a good website for playing with real-time visualizations. It uses WebGL and an in-page code editor, so you can edit a fragment shader and then run it live in your browser. One feature that was added (relatively) recently is the ability to connect a shader input to an audio stream - either from a pre-defined source, or from your microphone. You can also output sound from your shader by writing to a special `vec2` output. Here's [a list of examples that use mic input](https://www.shadertoy.com/results?query=&sort=popular&filter=soundinput).